# Is damage rerolled every time for cloudkill?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage

I know from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100149/does-the-spell-cloudkill-deal-damage-when-first-cast) that each PC rolls his or her saving throw against the *cloudkill* spell's poison at the start of each of his or her turns.

When calculating the damage a PC is dealt, is a new posion damage roll (5d8) made for each Constitution saving throw? Or, is one roll made when the spell would deal damage, then subsequently halved or not depending on the saving throw's success or failure?

Comment: Related or duplicate of https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61875/when-do-you-roll-the-damage-for-cloud-of-daggers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### You roll new damage each time the effect is triggered

> When    a    creature    enters    the    spell’s    area    for    the    first   time    on    a    turn    or    starts    its    turn    there,    that    creature  must    make    a    Constitution    saving    throw.    The
> creature    takes    5d8    poison    damage    on    a    failed    save,  or    half    as    much    damage    on    a    successful    one. (SRD. 125)

**There are two ways the effect can be triggered**, either a creature:

- starts it's turn within the area of effect, or
- enters the area of effect at any point during it's turn.

**And, when a creature does trigger the effect**, they immediately:

- make a saving throw, before
- taking 5d8 poison damage (or half on a succesful save).

The amount of damage is decided **after** the saving throw has been made by the creature and not before. So, it relates specifically to the creature that has triggered it, and made the saving throw, not any other creatures.

This is in direct contrast to 'Instantaneous' effect spells, which are not triggered by the target and deal damage once to multiple targets simultaeneously (ie. Burning Hands).

For evidence of this ruling, that you may consider authoratative, see [this Crawford tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/02/12/does-heat-metal-or-fire-shield-have-more-than-one-damage-roll/) on applying damage from other concentration spells which deal damage repeatedly.

**But if you find this too labour intensive, with your DM's permission you could choose to take the average instead, or roll once and keep applying the same figure.**

Beware, if rolling and keeping that figure, that the damage will be more extreme. A bad roll would nerf the spell for its whole duration, while a good roll that was applied consistently could seem overpowered. This could result in more metagaming - either from players knowing how much damage they'll take from a DMs spell in advance, or players deciding to drop concentration early, if they rolled poorly on damage, for their own spell.

A comprimise option, to save labour in crowded encounters, that avoids some of these issues, might be to roll damage once per round and apply that figure as necessary.

Comment: I use the one-roll-per-round option in my games for spells like this, it works out pretty well. I previously tried averages and then static damage, to much more meta-gamey effect.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. In answer to your labour saving options I found it didn't slow down combat rolling each time & it gave the players more worries about dying before they could do anything, especially as it just knocked out one of the lower level characters immediately. We do play on Roll20 so rolling dice is very fast.

Answer (score 3):

**Roll each time**

You can think of the dealing damage part as an instantaneous effect of the Cloudkill each turn. Each time the Cloudkill deals damage it is a separate saving throw and should be a separate damage roll.

Even without a saving throw, as seen on witch bolt (requires only a hit when cast and nothing else on consecutive turns), even if essentially the same spell separate instances of damages should be rolled each time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Whenever a creature enters the area for the first time or starts it turn in the area it makes a Constitution saving throw. Hence you would roll the damage then as well (half damage on successful save).